# New fields (items) in Notes documents somehow vanished. Replication problem?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, database-replication

I'll try to describe the situation:

- a Notes database, replicated to replicas on several servers
- by the way, it's late in the evening, very late... (say 23h)
- in one replica, we modified the design of a form to add another single-value text-field
- 5 minutes later, in same replica, we modified several documents, adding values to that field
- we also modified a view to reflects those new values (so we know they were there)
- the next day, the new items and values were gone, not even empty items were present
- all day, every hour, the database is replicated to at least two other servers
- there are no restrictive replication formulas
- during the night, replication is stopped
- also during the night, several agents are activated to update the documents
- none of the agents knows about the new field
- the form is set to Merge conflict in case of a conflict

I can't explain why those new fields/items and their values have been removed from the documents.

Can you?

Comment: Did the design changes to your form and view survive?

Comment: Strangely enough they did.

Comment: Well, it sounds like you had a conflict that was merged and the items were still lost. Perhaps if the merge occurs before the design replicates, the fact that the new items are not in the UNK table in the other replicas yet comes into play in how the merge logic tries to distinguish between added items and deleted items. It's an odd situation, for sure.

Comment: I've had a similar (and persistent) problem, although not with design elements.  I have two replicas, and the way the guy built the system, there's lots and lots of replications.  I added some code in a WQS agent to add a value to a field in a document in both two databases.  Later, I compare the two documents, and  in a small percentage of those comparisons, the field is missing.

Comment: The same new field was added to multiple different documents, albeit with different values. The next morning, none of those documents retained that value. How a design problem (unchanged form?) could be the cause I fail to see. I've always praised Notes replication, but now I'm starting to wonder... I regret I didn't check the Modification dates on those documents.

Comment: You mentioned that the Form is set to Merge Conflicts. Are you sure that all the docs in all the replicas have the $ConflictAction item set? IIRC, it has to be set in the document on both sides of the repication, otherwise weird things can happen - maybe depending on whether it's a push or pull.

Comment: So in cases where you've set Merge Conflicts on a form after a database has been in production for a while, you have to write an agent that updates $ConflictAction on all docs and replicate the docs across all servers -- and you have to do this while nothing else is happening in the database otherwise you get conflicts while tryng set $ConflictAction!

Comment: I checked all documents with the same form, in two of the replicas, and all of them have $ConflictAction="1". AFAIK Merge Conflicts was set from the start, on the other hand, most documents are generated and maintained by an agent that assembles info from other documents created using different forms. The agent never deletes a document.

Comment: I think it's probably a good idea to use ComputeWithForm in agents in order to make sure that $ConflictAction is set correctly, but since you've already verified that all docs have it set to 1, that doesn't seem to be the problem for you anyhow. Is it possible that you have multiple replicas of the same database on one or more servers? I've had cases where I was working on a weird problem for a week or two before I figured out that was the cause, so I might as well ask. You can probably check the database catalog in a By Replica Id view.

Comment: Ah, right, I should have mentioned that the servers have only one replica on any server. I'm familiar with the problems that occur when having 2 or more replicas, and all Help documents advise against it in the strongest terms.

Comment: We had one more bizarre issue, at the same time. I came back to my session late in the evening, working from home. A specific document was still open, and I had to save my changes. I got a warning that the document was saved elsewhere. So I didn't save, reopened the document, modified it and saved it. A few minutes later my colleague, working late as well from his home, contacted me to say that he had a similar problem. It turned out that Locking, which is enabled, no longer worked, for some reason. Could be related with the above, could be unrelated. Weird anyway.